# Can we fix translation related tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

I was about to edit the [`localization`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/localization/info) tag. Then I realized that there is no `internationalization` tag. However, there is a wrongly created `l18n` (should be `l10n`) tag as a tag synonym for `localization`, even though the correct synonym [`l10n`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l10n) exists separately. Also, `i18n` is set as another synonym for `localization`, although `internationalization` is a separate topic.

There is also a [`translation`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) tag which essentially has questions that are either related to `localization` or `internationalization`. Not to mention, there are separate tags for [`textdomain`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textdomain), [`language`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language), [`po`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/po) and [`mo`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mo), phew!

Finally, there is a separate [`multi-language`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-language) tag, which is rightly separate from the other tags I've mentioned above, although most of the questions there are not related to `multi-language`, but related to either `internationalization` or `localization` (i.e. `translation`).

I don't have the privileges to fix all that, and if I edit / alter all of these tag wiki, those who will approve it may become confused without proper context. That's the reason why I'm writing this question.

Now my question is: what should be the correct combination of tags related to translation?

My suggestion is, we need to have only two from all the above:

1. `translation` - all the others will be synonym to this.
2. `multi-language` - as it is a separate topic all together.

***OR,***

we can have 4:

1. `translation` - everything generally related to translation. With `language`, `x` (yes, it's already there) and `textdomain` synonyms.
2. `internationalization` - with `i18n` synonym.
3. `localization` - with `l10n`, `po`, `mo` synonyms.
4. `multi-language`

Please suggest.

## Update:

For ease of discussion, I'm providing the number of posts we have (at the time of writing this) against the available tags:

- [`localization`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/localization/info) (with synonym `i18n` and `l18n`) - 266
- [`l10n`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l10n) - 21
- [`translation`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) (with synonym `x`) - 344
- [`textdomain`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textdomain) - 41
- [`language`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) - 140
- [`po`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/po) - 30
- [`mo`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mo) - 21
- [`multi-language`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-language) - 267

Comment: Nice to see someone taking up the tag cleaning again!

Comment: Hint: you can use `[tag:name-of-tag]` syntax to directly convert them to linked tags. Example: [tag:localization]

Comment: @AndrewT. I didn't know about this tag linking shortcut, thanks :) However, I'm not sure why you are mentioning it though.

Comment: Just want to help you reduce the work, since I noticed you added the links manually... It also works with non-existence tags too.

Comment: Ah, got it. I thought perhaps there was another reason. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

Less is better. I like your first idea with just two tags. Most are not sure what tag to use, no matter what we try. Having less tags makes that easier.

I can do that, but it'll be quite some work that needs to be handled very carefully.

And more important, it needs the support of the active community members, so please raise your concerns now, or show your support!

Comment: I've done the first part, created the wiki for [`translation`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info) to cover both `internationalization` and `localization`. Please someone accept the edit or improve upon it.

Comment: @Fayaz Please don't do anything before we have a consensus!

Comment: Do we have a consensus yet? :)

Comment: @Fayaz Not sure. Very little engagement so far. :/

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of two tags only, but I would opt for `textdomain` in stead of `translation`.

The reason for this is that more serious developers, whom I see as our core users, will use `textdomain` to describe the development issue they are addressing. `translation` is a colloquial synonym, but not the correct WP term.

Comment: You can have translation problems where the text domain is not an issue at all, date i18n for example.

Comment: According to [WP translation handbook](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/) `localization`, `internationalization`, `textdomain` etc. all are part of the greater term `translation`. It's not only a well understood term among developers & English speaking people, it's well understood for non-English speaking people as well. Just think about it, the first word you'll ever learn if you are interested in translation is `translation` ;)

Comment: Also, AFAIK, people will still be able to tag and search by those synonyms, only system will properly merge them into one place. Not to mention that the total number of posts with all those tags combined suggests we can just have two.

Comment: I've updated the number of posts against each separate tags in the question, this should make further discussion easier.

Answer (score 2):

For me, out of the list of terms given, the ones that should not be there are translation, language, l10n, po and mo. translation is the process of producing text in different language which wordpress has nothing to do with, the rest are just not meaningful.

textdomain is a technical term used as part of localization so it should stay, localization obviously should stay, and multi language (should be multi locale but lol no one will use or understand it) is a way to set wordpress for multiple localizations.

BTW  i18n for me is not a useful term, in many countries you need to handle two or more languages just for the country itself, calling it a i18n is a little be of stretch. So maybe i18n should be a synonym of localization.

.. and out of https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-i18n

> Internationalization is the design and development of a product, application or document content that **enables** easy localization for target audiences that vary in culture, region, or language.

Comment: I agree that terms such as `po`, `mo` are useless. However, not having them as synonym means new uses will add them to the system again! Also, WP core heavily uses the terminology [`translation`](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/), which is further divided into two parts: [internationalization (i18n) & localization (l10n)](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/#terms). So even though these terms are generic & often used interchangeably, having them as tags and synonyms are useful. The challenge is to determine which should be the main tag and which should go to synonym.

Comment: agree on the use of whatever synonyms as needed. As for translation, the process is indeed translation, but that is orthogonal to development. Unless wordpress is integrating with something like google translate, there is very little software in core which is related to translating..... maybe use translation API to relate to the __ and _e function might be a good alternative. i18n is the assistance of the __ API at all, and not related much to plugin/theme development, except in a very high level way.

Comment: As for codex people not knowing official meaning of english words, it is refreshing to complain about something else than the quality of the examples in the codex ;)